# Unhandled Rejection (Error) reducer is returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

Server throws error "Unhandled Rejection" while rendering Search Component. I had put return statement on both of the case while writing reducers.

[image]

**Code in Action File:**

```js
export const NEWS = "NEWS";

export function news(items) {
    const action = {
        type: NEWS,
        items
    }
    return action;
}
```

**Code in Reducer File:**

```js
import { NEWS } from '../actions';

export default function news

(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case NEWS:
            console.log("News are ",action.items);
            return {...state, news: action.items};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**This is my search function.**

```js
class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        query: ''
      };
    }

    search(){
        console.log('Search button clicked', this.state.query);
        const url = `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${this.state.query}`;
        // console.log(url);
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(response=> response.json())
        .then(jsonObj => {this.props.news(jsonObj.results)});
    }
```

**This is NewsResults.js code where I am using mapStateToProps function**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Search from './Search';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class NewsResults extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>
              Search Results:
            </h2>
            <Search/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    };

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        news: state.news
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(NewsResults);
```

** This is what my redux store looks like in index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, 
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Try `state = [{}], `

Comment: what is the data shape you want for your state? `state=[]` or `state={ news: [] }`?

Comment: @codekaizer I tried both and it didn't work. I am just trying to get list of news that I search for.

Comment: wait, the error says unhandled rejection. So your request had failed and wasn't `catch`ed. Try adding `.catch(error => console.log(error))` after `then` to see the detailed error.

Comment: catch error didn't help since it just gave the same error. I have edit some more of my react code in the question, might be useful in helping me. @codekaizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state you are giving to the reducer is a list, to which you are assigning values as if it were an object. change the reducer to have state = initialState = {}

```
const initialState = {}
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
        // your cases
    default:
    return state
   }
}
```